# JSF 1.1 on Websphere 7

Tags: jsf, websphere-7

I am having an application which was developed using JSF 1.1 components. The tag libraries development team, is not going to support JSF 1.2, and we have to run the application on Webshere 7. As websphere 7, by default comes with JSF 1.2. Initially, i was able to deploy my application, but was unable to access it. Later, I read somewhere to remove "Precompile JSP" option, i did that and i was able to access the application. But i am facing some weird thing, first time i am able to login to application, but if i logout and then tries to login again, it is giving exceptions. The exception is `javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: Exception while invoking expression #{login.authenticate}`, where login is my bean name and authenticate is the method. Moreover, I want some other way, so that i should keep "Precompile jsp" option selected. I read somewhere about shared libraries, but not aware how to actually implement that. My war file contains jsf-api.jar and jsf-impl.jar of JSF 1.1.

Answer (score 1):

Do you see some errors regarding propertyLoader? I had similar problem, and removed from config file custom propertyLoader (left standart), and it became almost ok.